# Laravel - Model creating with subquery

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have an `items` table that has a `sequence` column which its value should be the result of a subquery:

```
INSERT INTO items (company_id, sequence, name)
    VALUES (1, (
            SELECT
                COALESCE(max(i.sequence), 0) + 1
            FROM
                items AS i
            WHERE
                company_id = 1), 'item 1 of company 1')
```

But in Laravel I'm using Eloquent mass assignment with `create` method to insert my `items` records:

```
$company->items()->create($inputs);
```

How to define the model `sequence` attribute as a raw subquery on creating records via mass assignment?

Comment: I'm not sure the error is related to what you're asking.  Mass assignment is related to one of the fields being guarded, or not fillable, in your model definition.  In regards to what you're asking, what does $inputs contain?

Comment: @Devon `$inputs`is the array of fillable attributes. I just want a way to set the `sequence` attribute as a raw SQL (like the subquery in the example)

Comment: @Devon is not mandatory to make `sequence` as fillable if there is another way to set his value as subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the likelyhood of two entries for the same company in less than a second?  I'm sure it's so unlikely that you probably don't need to use a raw statement here.  While this is ever-so-slightly more subject to a race condition, it greatly simplifies your problem when using Eloquent..

```
$inputs['sequence'] = ($company->items()->max('sequence') ?? 0) + 1;
$company->items()->create($inputs);
```

Comment: 1. select max...
2. insert into...

you can resume this into only one statement

Comment: It's the same query as what you have, just not run as a subquery...  This also prevents you from having to do a refresh().

Comment: yes, looking for the downside of doing refresh this approach makes sense.

Comment: but what about concurrent inserts? someone inserting a new record after fetching `max(sequence)` and before `create`? don't you think that the one-statement would prevent this?

Comment: Like I said in the answer, what are the chances that happens for the same company in a very small amount of time (like milliseconds)?  I doubt it's something to worry about unless you're dealing with something highly sensitive.  Without locking, both are subject to race conditions, this slightly more subject to it, but it's a very small chance.

Comment: Ok, your point is good even because in my case, `sequence` are unique for `company_id`. So if the constraint fails, I can just retry 3 times to insert with, for example: `DB::transaction($store, 3)`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will have two ways to go about this, either using model events on the `items` model to set that `sequence` field anytime the model is saved, or combining your `$inputs` array with the result of the sub query. 
The first option, using model events. You just add the event listener in the `Items` model:

```
protected static function boot(){
    static::saving(function($thisModel){
        $thisModel->attributes['sequence'] = your sub query;
    });
}
```

This will updated the sequence any time the model is saved. This might be nice if you know that it will need to be updated any time it is saved. You can change `saving` to `creating` if this is only something that needs to be done on creation. There are a lot of other options if neither of these are what you need.

The other option would be to just have a different query added to the `$inputs` array.

```
$subQuery = your sub query, using whatever you like. 
$company->items()->create($inputs + ['sequence' => $subQuery]);
```

The array union operator `+` should be fine to use.

Comment: I came into these two solutions with usage of `DB::raw('subquery')`. The only issue 
 with this approach is that I don't know the side effects of setting a model attribute as subquery. So actually I'm running `$model->refresh();` right after creating because else $model->sequence === subquery instead of database value...

Comment: hmm, that is an interesting problem. Have you seen what a `setSequenceAttribute()` would do in this situation? If you called the sub query in the setter would the sequence === subquery I wonder.

Comment: It could be a different issue entirely, since `DB::raw()` always returns a standard object. Are you retrieving just the returned value you need from the object when you save it?